# Application of Fubini and Tonelli Theorems.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am studying product measures (From Real Analysis, Royden), basically the application of Fubini and Tonelli theorems.
As much as I understand the theorems, I find it difficult  doing computation with the theorems because  I am finding it difficult  to grasp some of the concepts.
I don't know if it is acceptable here, I have an old notes with a specific problem that I need help understanding, a picture is posted below.
[image]

Concern 1:
Why is it that when we  fix $x$, we  have $f(x,y)=0$ a.e [I am thinking it is so because if we fix $x$ then there is only one possible value of $y$, $y=x$ that gives us f(x,y)=1] and so $\int_Xf(x,y)d\mu=0$ But when we fix a $y$ it says $f(x,x)=1$ and $\int_Yf(x,y)d\nu=1$ ?
I know the $\sigma$-finiteness condition is violated by the counting measure. but I dont know why there should be any difference in $f$ between when $x$ is fixed and when $y$ is fixed. I was thinking it should be same.

Could someone help clarify that for me, kindly add any other relevant information I may be misssing.
And please pardon me if the question doesnt seem well structured. I am  new to the product measure concept. Bu I will be glad to clarify if anything is unclear. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For fixed $x$, $f(x,y)=1$ only when $x=y$. But $\mu(\{x\})=0$ so that $f(x,y)=0$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\int_X f(x,y)d\mu(x)=0$. On the other hand, when $y$ is fixed $\int_Y f(x,y)d\nu(y)=1\times\nu(\{y\})=1$.

Comment: Wow, as if I was under a spell. I see everything clear now. Thank you so much. Basically nothing changed with the function. The difference is from the fact that the measure of set where $f \neq 0$ differs among the two measures.